# Twig does not replace blocks from child template

Tags: twig

I have a simple setup. A parent template with some {% block ... %} elements and a child template which defines those elements.

Oddly (to me as a beginner), no {% block ... %} element is recognized.

The code:

```
{# main.twig #}

Hello {% block greeting %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

```
{# child.twig #}

{% extends "main.twig" %}

{% block greeting %}friend{% endblock %}

{% block body %}Some text{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}{% endblock %}
```

This is already not working

Here a (not working) example of the exact problem:

https://twigfiddle.com/p2i0ix

In the example I also added a third level:

```
{# child_extend.twig #}

{% extends "child.twig" %}

{% block footer %}Footer text{% endblock %}
```

As you can see in the example, no {% block ... %} gets output.

Naturally I want all my blocks to get replaced and shown in the respective templates.

I am surely missing something blindingly obvious.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Just edited my post to insert the example code. Also, initially I thought only one block gets output. But none get recognized. Edited to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your twigfiddle, check the file you want to test as the main template.

If you want to test `child.twig`, check this as the main template.

The other problem is that the block foot is not the main file, from which it does not appear.

either you put it in the main file, or you can do something like that:

```
{# child.twig #}

{% extends "main.twig" %}

{% block greeting %}friend{% endblock %}

{% block body %}Some text
{% block footer %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

It's just for the example, the better is to put the block footer in the main file and only fill in the file `child_extend.twig`

```
{# main.twig #}

Hello {% block greeting %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}{% endblock %}

-------------------------------
{# child.twig #}

{% extends "main.twig" %}

{% block greeting %}friend{% endblock %}

{% block body %}Some text{% endblock %}

-------------------------------
{# child_extend.twig #}

{% extends "child.twig" %}

{% block footer %}Footer text{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I now understand the idea behind the twigfiddle "main template". The footer mistake crept in due to the example. Thank you for pointing that out. The example now works. Since I am using Symfony 4, I might have an error there somewhere which prevents the blocks from being included. Will look at it again and open another question, if necessary. Thank you.